# C++ function with any parameters make Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, parameters, segmentation-fault, variadic-functions

Here is my program, anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdarg.h>
using namespace std;

void say(char* name ...)
{
    cout << "Hello, ";
    cout << name ;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,name);

    for(;;){
        char* str = va_arg(ap, char*);
        if (str == 0) break;
        cout << ", " << str;
    }
    cout << endl;
    va_end(ap);
}
int main()
{
    char *a = "atom";
    char *b = "johhny";
    char *c = "jim";
    say(a,b,c);
}
```

When I run it, I got this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003f0b06fed0 in strlen () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
```

Here is the debug info:

```
24      cout << "Hello, ";
(gdb) n
25      cout << name ;
(gdb) n
27      va_start(ap,name);
(gdb) n
30          char* str = va_arg(ap, char*);
(gdb) n
31          if (str == 0) break;
(gdb) n
32          cout << ", " << str;
(gdb) n
29      for(;;){
(gdb) n
30          char* str = va_arg(ap, char*);
(gdb) n
31          if (str == 0) break;
(gdb) n
32          cout << ", " << str;
(gdb) n
29      for(;;){
(gdb) n
30          char* str = va_arg(ap, char*);
(gdb) n
31          if (str == 0) break;
(gdb) n
32          cout << ", " << str;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003f0b06fed0 in strlen () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function strlen,
which has no line number information.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

Comment: `if (str == 0) break;` - what does this do in practice?

Comment: Next time you step through some code in the debugger, and you know when and where the crash will happen, *do* take a look at the variables involved. That would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: Off topic: if you can use C++11, take a look at variadic template. It can achieve exactly same thing with more security (you can pass different type which are known at compile time, number of parameter are known at compile time, ...)

Answer (score 4):

Calling `va_arg` more times than the actual number of arguments is undefined behavior. You don't have any automatic way to detect the end of output. You have to keep track of number of valid arguments yourself. There are multiple ways to do that, for example:

- You can pass a null or any special value to signal end.
- You can pass the number of arguments as a separate mandatory argument.
- You can maintain some sort of formatting string like `printf` or `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code relies on seeing a `NULL`, but the caller does not supply it.

`va_arg` has no idea when your argument list has ended. When your code does this

```
if (str == 0) break;
```

for the fourth time, it retrieves some junk past the end of vararg list, and tries dereferencing it. This is what causes undefined behavior, which results in a crash.

Passing it explicitly fixes the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/jxItrA)):

```
say(a,b,c, (char*)0);
```

Comment: To expand on passing `(char*)0` to end the arguments list: Using `nullptr` instead puts a `nullptr_t` object on the stack. While it can be used to be compared against any other pointer it is not by itself a pointer, and really not compatible with the `va_arg(ap, char*)` macro call.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg: I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Me to, I'll keep the comment though, for reference of future visitors.